# Where is the "Static Front Page" menu gone?

Tags: wordpress

On my own installed WP (Version 4.4) I didn't get the "Static Front Page" menu item in the Customizer? In my demo account under https://wordpress.com/customize/mydemo.wordpress.com I got for the same theme the missing menu item?

Also there is no option to set the front page under "Dashboard > Settings > Reading"? Do I need a special plugin?

Answer (score 1):

The solution found by chance:

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/front-page-displays-option-missing

In short for my case:

The both missing menu items in my own installed WP (Version 4.4) appear when the status of the page or post is not "private" and "published".